# Жесткий диск пропал, как вернуть без потери данных?

Tags: windows, hdd, smart

Система SSD (система) + HDD Windows10
Недавно был ремонт, отключали электричество на 10 минут. ПК был преждевременно выключен за пару минут до отключения электричества.
После запуска система тормозит, но не критично. Жесткий диск не виден в проводнике, в DiskManagement помечен как Not Initialized, Unallocated, черный цвет. При попытке инициализации долго грузит и выдает ошибку "The request could not be preformed becouse of an I/O device error".

CrystalDiskInfo (8.17.3) при пересканировании нашел диск с ошибкой в S.M.A.R.T. 197 (C5) Current Pending Sector Count, 200, 200, 0, 000000000001. [image: Скрин из CrystalDiskInfo]
Сверху прикреплен скрин. На ссылке лежит полная информация из CrystalDiskInfo

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13gUwOwv5OWtncwpf8UlLFrZDhq6tD0RR?usp=sharing

Минутка позитива: после обнаружения проблемы также обнаружилось, что надпись активации windows исчезла и не появляется до сего момента

Comment: Уважаемые модераторы, пожалуйста, не закрывайте вопрос хотя бы в течении двух суток. Я понимаю, что вопрос не относится к программированию, но уверен, что некоторые из нас сталкивались с такими неприятностями и способны уверенно и конструктивно ответить на поставленный вопрос. Более того решение необходимо срочно.

Comment: «При попытке инициализации» — это вы зря конечно, если там что-то смогло выполниться, то наверняка таблицу разделов теперь затёрли

Comment: @andreymal звучит ужасно, это приведет к полной неспособности восстановить данные или ещё есть выход?

Comment: Попробуйте для начала шлейфы все перевоткнуть. И с питанием и с данными. И проверьте, что диски не выпали в PIO mode из режима UDMA (Ultra DMA). Хотя может в современных системах это и не актуально, но я бы проверил.

Comment: @CrazyElf позвольте спросить: а как это собственно проверить в каком режиме PIO находится диск? Насколько я понял из CrystalDiskInfo с UDMA нет никаких ошибок или вы имеете ввиду другое?

Comment: Хотя нет, наверное это для SATA дисков не актуально, я гоню )  А так это в свойствах контроллеров в устройствах винды смотрится. А насчёт шлейфов я серьёзно, у меня лично были прецеденты. Но может и просто таблица разделов затёрлась как-то сама, это тоже бывает, тогда только каким r-Studio данные с диска вынимать

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, но все равно проблема пока не решена. мне кажется, что если бы дело было в шлейфе, то комп бы даже не видел HDD

Comment: Находишь такой же винт по размеру, цепляешь к компу, грузишь linux livecd на котором есть `ddrescue`, дампишь твой винт на донора В ВИДЕ ОБРАЗА (фс на новом винте нужно создать), потом подрубаешь донора к винде и долбишься с R-Studio и EasyRecovery. А первый винт загоняешь на тест через mhdd.

Comment: @donRumata большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, что конкретно привело к решению проблемы, ведь результата буквально вчера ещё не было никакого, но сегодня проблемы больше не существует. Предполагаю, что советы, данные мне в комментариях @CrazyElf и @donRumata действительно работают, но не сразу. Возможно, в будущем я обнаружу некоторые артефакты поломки, но на данный момент я закрываю вопрос.

Comment: Шлейф может как-то не до конца прилегать, в результате диск может то видеться, то отваливаться, видеться как-то частично и т.п. Говорю же - у меня был такой случай, когда шлейф как-то понемногу отваливался, после этого я стараюсь использовать только шлейфы SATA с защёлками )  Хотя не исключены и другие глюки как харда так и софта

Comment: @CrazyElf предполагаю, что совпало сразу несколько факторов. Ненадежное крепление и долгое выключение компьютера (либо процессы, которые решили сами по себе активироваться и после выключения)